# RemoteApp and Desktop Connections Error 0x800401F0 when updating RemoteApp connections from RDS webfeed

Tags: windows-server-2012, rds, remoteapp

I have set up Windows Server 2012 with Remote Desktop Services and RemoteApp aplications.
Windows 7 clients are configured with web feed of RemoteApp aplications.
Update is working when I manualy click "Update Now" in "RemoteApp and Desktop Connections" window, and new application icons are added.

But automatic update always fail with (from event log) :

```
An error occurred. Contact your workplace administrator for assistance.

Connection name: Work Resources
Connection URL: https://srv-thor.du.laus.hr/RDWeb/Feed/webfeed.aspx
Error code: 0x800401F0, 0x0
```

UPDATE :::::::::::::::::

see exported functions in tsworkspace_dll :
(from http://www.nirsoft.net/dll_information/windows8/tsworkspace_dll.html)

```
RADCProcessGroupPolicyEx
TaskUpdateWorkspaces
TaskUpdateWorkspaces2
TaskUpdateWorkspacesIfNeeded
```

So i tried :
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\RUNDLL32 tsworkspace,TaskUpdateWorkspaces

and it works from cmd line and from scheduled task !

Scheduled Tasks - > Windows -> remotreApp and Desktop Conenctions Update -> [user@domain]

But 10 mins after that I get an error again but none of scheduled tasks is executed, something else is trigerring update ???